# To extract content of 1st column (all rows) from an .xlsx file and replace it with the extracted information from each column

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv, parsing

I have to replace first entire column (all rows) with  information extracted from each column itself. Last digit is missing for each column with my code.

I have coded but had to save the output to a different file. I am unable to figure out how to replace the first column of the existing file itself. I need one file with the required output only.

```
fname = 'output.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)

sheet = wb.active

print('The sheet title is: ', sheet.title)

row_a = sheet['A']

d = []

for cell in row_a:

    a = cell.value
    d.append(a)
print(d)

s = []

for i in d:

    i = i[-1:-8]
    s.append(i)
print('The list of account numbers is: ', s)

wc = xlwt.Workbook()

ws = wc.add_sheet('Sheet1')


row=0

col=0

list_d = s

for item in list_d:

    ws.write(row, col, item)

    row+=1

wc.save('FINAL.xls')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using python's builtin [`string.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method:

```
import openpyxl


fname = 'output.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)
sheet = wb.active

d = [cell.value for cell in sheet['A']]  # List comprehension to replace your for loop

# str.split splits the 'Name' column data into an array of strings
# selecting [-1] selects only the account number
s = [i.split('.')[-1] for i in d]
s[0] = 'Account'  # replace 'Name' with 'Account' for column header

row = 1
col = 1

for item in s:
    sheet.cell(row, col).value = item
    row += 1

wb.save(fname)
```

I also added [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), which are a more Pythonic way of creating arrays from data in many cases.

Comment: Thank you Sparrow1029 for helping on extracting the correct account number and name. However there is another main part of the problem. I don't want another file (Final) but want to amend the existing output file itself by writing the extracted information. I am unable to figure out how to do it ...Can you please suggest ?

Comment: Ah okay, so you want replace the **Name** column with **Account** and the corresponding numbers exactly as your output above... I amended the code above to reflect that. Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your help. I have to learn a lot about Python. Wish I can be good someday soon :)

Comment: You are very welcome! Python is a programming language with similar concepts as any other. Once you master the basics, it's all downhill from there :) good luck on your journey!